# Replaced /usr/bin/vim - now I get error messages

Tags: macvim

I tried to upgrade from the default vim install on Mac OS X (vim 7.2) to the one used by MacVim (vim 7.3) by creating a symlink:

```
ln -s /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim /usr/bin/vim
```

However, now I get the following error messages:

```
sk@supernova:~/ > /usr/bin/vim
E254: Cannot allocate color Red
E254: Cannot allocate color White
E254: Cannot allocate color Blue
E254: Cannot allocate color Red
E254: Cannot allocate color Grey
E254: Cannot allocate color Blue
E254: Cannot allocate color Brown
E254: Cannot allocate color SeaGreen
E254: Cannot allocate color SeaGreen
E254: Cannot allocate color Yellow
E254: Cannot allocate color Red
E254: Cannot allocate color Blue
E254: Cannot allocate color Magenta
E254: Cannot allocate color DarkCyan
E254: Cannot allocate color LightMagenta
E254: Cannot allocate color Grey
E254: Cannot allocate color Blue
E254: Cannot allocate color Magenta
E254: Cannot allocate color Red
E254: Cannot allocate color Yellow
E254: Cannot allocate color Black
E254: Cannot allocate color LightGrey
E254: Cannot allocate color DarkBlue
E254: Cannot allocate color Grey
E254: Cannot allocate color DarkBlue
E254: Cannot allocate color Grey
E254: Cannot allocate color DarkBlue
E254: Cannot allocate color LightGrey
E254: Cannot allocate color LightBlue
E254: Cannot allocate color LightMagenta
E254: Cannot allocate color Blue
E254: Cannot allocate color LightCyan
E254: Cannot allocate color LightGrey
E254: Cannot allocate color Grey90
E254: Cannot allocate color Grey90
E254: Cannot allocate color LightRed
E254: Cannot allocate color DarkGrey
E254: Cannot allocate color LightGrey
E254: Cannot allocate color Cyan
Error detected while processing /Users/sk/.vimrc:
line    1:
E185: Cannot find color scheme desert
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Anyone knows how to fix this? If I run just `vim` or `/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim` directly I don't get the error messages. Only if `/usr/local/bin/vim` gets called. Either directly or via another command line application.

---

Just if someone comments that I could have simply created an alias, I actually did that before

```
alias vim=/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/vim
```

however, some other command line tools were still using `/usr/bin/vim`.

Comment: Actually the full listing of what fg colors are available are hard coded.

https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/blob/master/src/syntax.c#L7580-L7587

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a known issue. From `:help MacVim`:

```
Note: Starting MacVim by creating a symlink to >
    .../MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim with 'ln -s' does not work.
```

I found a lot of people getting a string of E254 errors from using a symlink. See [this ticket](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/issues/attachmentText?id=204&aid=-5898638510778073995&name=macvimerr-1.txt&token=539d471a7487192b085b250770f71bfd) on the MacVim issue repository. The solution follows:

```
    Most likely this is because you have symlinked directly to
    the Vim binary, which Cocoa does not allow.  Please use an
    alias or the mvim shell script instead.
```

MacVim comes with a startup shell script, `mvim`. You can alias it to `vim` if you'd prefer to use it instead of the system vim. If you want to start vim in the terminal rather than as a gui application, set the alias to `mvim -v`. Add `export EDITOR=vim` to your `~/.bash_profile` to make sure that any terminal applications are using the now-aliased vim. This should cover all your bases.

Answer (score 4):

Changing something in /usr/bin is not the best way to go about things as Apple can just overwrite it again.

The errors are probably as @karmatic says but probably the best thing to do here is put the symbolic link in /usr/local/bin and make your shell have that in the path earlier than /usr/bin.

As far as I know no command line tool uses /usr/bin/vi directly (I use emacs so I would spot having to use vi) What they do is use the environment variable $EDITOR so set that to /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any rep yet so I can't comment on michaelmichael's answer but based on his answer I edited the `mvim` wrapper script to add another case statement. So that if $name was `vim` it will add the `-v` option. I then symlinked `/usr/local/bin/mvim` to `/usr/local/bin/vim`.

```
47 # vimdiff, view, and ex mode
48 case "$name" in
49     vim)
50         opts="$opts -v"
51         ;;
52     *vimdiff)
```

This was all because in some cases I couldn't rely on EDITOR being set or on aliases but I could rely on /usr/local/bin being in PATH.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it has something to do with your color scheme. Deactivate the desert theme in your .vimrc and see whether it helps.
Change `colorscheme desert` to `'colorscheme desert`.

The best way to avoid such problems is to install vim 7.3 from the [mac ports](http://www.macports.org/).

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried that before. I then don't get the `E185: Cannot find color scheme desert` error, but still all the others.

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend using homebrew's `--with-override-system-vim`.

Installs MacVim and creates the /usr/local/bin/vim symlink. Works for command line `vim` as well as invocations of `EDITOR`.

Here's the command:

```
brew install macvim --with-override-system-vim
```

(On a side note, the brew version of MacVim works well with YouCompleteMe plugin)

Answer (score -1):

`brew install vim`

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/vim/<VIM_VERSION>/bin/vim /usr/bin/vim`

By the way, if OS is EI Capitan , you have to disable SIP as blow:

[How do I disable SIP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11)